# Keeping track of which is the smallest and which is the largest value so far in a loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

could you please help me with solving simple problem? I am very fresh with C++ and learning from book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup". I have never learnt C++ before so I am not familiar with many useful features. The drill says:

> "6. Now change the body of the loop so that it reads just one double
>   each time around. Define two variables to keep track of which is the
>   smallest and which is the largest value you have seen so far. Each
>   time through the loop write out the value entered. If it’s the
>   smallest so far, write the smallest so far after the number. If it is
>   the largest so far, write the largest so far after the number"

I do not know how to do this correctly without using vector. Here is my code:

```
#include "C:/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double a, b,differ=0;
    char c=' ';
    cout << "Enter two values: \n";
    while (c != '|' && cin >> a >> b )
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            cout << "The smaller value is: "<< b << " and the larger value is: " << a << "\n \n";
            differ = a - b;
            if (differ < 1.0 / 100)
                cout << "Numbers are almost equal\n\n";
        }
        else if (a < b)
        {
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << a << " and the larger value is: " << b << "\n \n";
            differ = b - a;
            if (differ < 1.0 / 100)
                cout << "Numbers are almost equal\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "These values are equal!\n";
        }
        cout << "Enter a character | to break loop: \n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    cout << "You have exited the loop.\n";
    keep_window_open();
}
```

And here are previous steps, these I have solved with code above:

> 1. Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the
>      program when a terminating '|' is entered.
>
>    2. Change the program to write out the smaller value is: followed by the smaller of the numbers and the larger value is: followed by the
>         larger value.
>    3. Augment the program so that it writes the line the numbers are equal (only) if they are equal.
>    4. Change the program so that it uses doubles instead of ints.
>    5. Change the program so that it writes out the numbers are almost equal after writing out which is the larger and the smaller if the two
>         numbers differ by less than 1.0/100.

Could you give me some hint how to do step 6.? I had some ideas but none of them worked..

Here is new code:

```
#include "C:/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double smallestSoFar = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double largestSoFar = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    double a,differ=0;
    char c=' ';
    cout << "Enter value: \n";

    while (c != '|' && cin >> a)
    {
        if (a > largestSoFar)
        {
            largestSoFar = a; 
            cout <<"Largest so far is: "<< largestSoFar << endl;
        }
        else if (a < smallestSoFar)
        {
            smallestSoFar = a;
            cout <<"Smallest so far is: "<< smallestSoFar << endl;
        }
        else if(smallestSoFar >= a && a<=largestSoFar)
            cout << a << endl;
        cout << "Enter a character | to break loop: \n";
        cin >> c;
    }
    cout << "You have exited the loop.\n";
    keep_window_open();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not know how to do this correctly without using vector.

You do not need vector for this. The description correctly says that two variables would be sufficient:

```
// Declare these variables before the loop
double smallestSoFar = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double largestSoFar = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
```

Modify your loop to read into `a`, not into both `a` and `b`. Check the newly entered value against `smallestSoFar` and `largestSoFar`, do the printing, and re-assign smallest and largest as necessary. Note that the first time around you should see both printouts - for largest so far and for smallest so far.

Comment: I have improved code, could you take a look above at my first post? I edited it and placed new code there. I dont understand it well, but it seems to work. Is the code ok?

Comment: @Michael Yes, that, the right code. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the knowledge that you are suppose to know at the current stage for the this assignment. The code should go something like this:

```
#include < iostream>
#include < cstdlib>

 int main() {

 double num_1 = 0;
 double num_2 = 0;
 double largest = 0;
 double smallest = 0;

 bool condition1 = true;

 while (true) {

    std::cin >> num_1;

    if (num_1 > largest){
        largest = num_1;
    }
    else if (num_1 < smallest) {
        smallest = num_1;
    }
    
    std::cout << "The largest so far: " << largest << std::endl;

    std::cin >> num_2;
    
    if (condition1) {
        smallest = largest;
        condition1 = false;
    }

    if (num_2 < smallest) {
        smallest = num_2;
    }
    else if (num_2 > largest) {
        largest = num_2;
    }
    
    std::cout << "The smallest so far: " << smallest << std::endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double large = 0;
double small = 0;

double input;
int counter = 0;

while (counter < 5) {
    cin >> input;
    cout <<"Large value: "<< large << '\t' <<"Small value: "<< small\
        << '\t' <<"Input value: "<< input << '\n';
    if (input < small) {
        cout << "The smallest value is " << input<<\
            "\nthe largest value is "<< large<<'\n';
        small = input;
    }

    else if (input > small&& input < large) {
        cout << "The smallest value is " << small << \
            "\nthe largest value is " << large<<'\n';
    }
    else if (input > small&& input > large) {
        cout << "The smallest value is " << small << \
            "\nthe largest value is " << input << '\n';
        large = input;
    }
    counter += 1;
```

Comment: ``large`` and ``small`` initializations are not correct. ``large`` should be smallest possible at start, ``small`` should be largest possible at start.

Comment: Forgot the initialization by mistake when copying code. How should large and small change? By putting large/small = input before the cout statement?